# Applying LinearRegression on grouped datasets leveraging pyspark computation power

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, linear-regression, data-analysis

I have a large dataset that is grouped by a column `SEQ_ID`. Currently, I am using the Linear regression from the `pyspark.ml.regression` library by looping it through each `SEQ_ID` which completely defeats the purpose of spark computing.
I have 20 nodes running and it uses only 2 nodes or so for doing the calculation, not to mention that it is very slow and the jobs run to the ten-thousands.

Is there a way to apply a `groupBy()` like function to the LinearRegression?

Here is the code I am using:

```
pred_all=[] 
seq_id=df.select('SEQ_ID').distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
for i in range(0,cnt):
    df1=df.filter((col('SEQ_ID')==seq_id[i]))
    vect_assm = VectorAssembler(inputCols =['Norm_time'], outputCol='features')
    df_vect=vect_assm.transform(df1)
    lir = LinearRegression(featuresCol = 'features', labelCol='Norm_Med', maxIter=5, regParam=0, elasticNetParam=0)
    model = lir.fit(df_vect)
    predictions = model.transform(df_vect)
    pred_all.append(predictions)
pred_final=reduce(DataFrame.unionByName, pred_all)
```

This is the result:

```
pred_final.show()
+-------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| SEQ_ID|           Norm_time|           Norm_Med|         prediction|
+-------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|3922758|                 0.0| 0.3776243351684084|  0.289517569092887|
|3922758|5.138936868160574...|0.44322105066716916| 0.2895221913527707|
|3922758|0.003989201706942744|0.44322105066716916|0.28987638118750636|
|3922758|0.004034881145770839|  0.397032751702913| 0.2898804898629585|
|3922758| 0.00409687466989468|  0.397032751702913|0.28988606592250066|
|3922758|0.004177629392108632|  0.397032751702913| 0.2898933294737464|
|3922758|0.004309365630871...|  0.397032751702913|0.28990517860027354|
|3936260|                 0.0|0.20430783102133815| 0.2702994786579788|
|3936260|5.401451910273482E-5|0.20430783102133815|0.27029797782640164|
|3936260|1.084291457543787...|0.20626289562181127|0.27029646587755346|
|3936260|1.628437724060227...|0.20626289562181127|0.27029495392870534|
|3936260|2.412648519922155E-4|0.20626289562181127|0.27029277494360066|
|3936260|3.280881901055003...|0.20626289562181127| 0.2702903624958062|
|3936260|3.901048601864181E-4| 0.2053554369382217|0.27028863931881014|
|3936260| 4.96133360647342E-4|0.20467513615862443|0.27028569324201046|
|3936260|0.001442787821366...|0.20430783102133815| 0.2702593897789611|
```